# 'str' object has no atribute 'read', json.load

Tags: python, json, dictionary

so I am trying to get a random word for a project and I never used read in my code
speaking of here's my code

```
import json
import random

Dictonaryftg = json.load("EnglishDictionary.json")

Words = list(Dictonaryftg.keys())

Rword = str(random.choice(Words))

print(Rword)
```

im pretty sure my issue resides here:

```
random.choice(Words)
```

But i can't find the issue

Comment: why would you omit the full error message and the stack trace, which tells you **exactly where in your code the error is coming from?**

Answer (score 0):

The code should be

```
import json
import random

with open("EnglishDictionary.json", 'r') as f:
    Dictonaryftg = json.load(f)
```

The issue is that, `json.load` expects a file object, where you just passed the file name i.e. a string object.